# Determine the orthogonal complement of the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ given by

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal

> Determine the orthogonal complement of the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ given by:
>   $$V=\{(x,y,z)^T:x-y=0\}$$
>   and find an orthonormal basis for it.

**My try:**

$x-y=0\implies x=y$
$$\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} y \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix}=y\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}+z\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
Let $u_1=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix},u_2=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$
$$u_1\cdot u_2=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}\cdot \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}=0$$So, they are orthogonal.

And to determine the orthonormal basis I need to used Gram-Schmidt right?

Can anyone tell whether I am doing right or wrong?

Comment: You’ve found a basis for $V$, not for its orthogonal complement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$V$ is a two-dimensional subspace, spanned by
$$
\left[\begin{array}{c}1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{array}\right],\;\left[\begin{array}{c}0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{array}\right].
$$
The orthogonal complement of $V$ is a one-dimensional subspaced, spanned by

$$
\left[\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{array}\right].
$$
So an orthonormal basis of $V^{\perp}$ is 
$$
  \left\{ \left[\begin{array}{c} 1/\sqrt{2} \\ -1/\sqrt{2} \\ 0 \end{array}\right]\right\}
$$

Comment: How did you get The orthogonal complement of $V$ is a one-dimensional subspaced, spanned by as

$\left[\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{array}\right].$

Comment: @philip : Any vector orthogonal to the first vector of my first equation must be of the form $\left[\begin{array}{c} x \\ -x \\ y \end{array}\right]$, and the only vectors of this form that are also orthogonal to the second vector on that line must have $y=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Vectors with $x=y$ belong to $V$. You’ve found a basis for $V$, not for its orthogonal complement.

If you interpret the left-hand side of $V$’s defining equation as a dot product, what is says is that $V$ consists of all vectors that are orthogonal to a particular fixed vector. It should be pretty clear, then, that all vectors orthogonal to $V$ are scalar multiples of this fixed vector. To get an orthonormal basis for $V^\perp$ all you need to do is normalize this vector, which I’ll leave to you to figure out.